# how to use kubectl -o jsonpath if key have '.'?

Tags: jsonpath

I went to get a value in yaml.
so I use a kubeclt ~~ -o jsonpath=~~~
if key have '.' what should command make?

ex)
apiVersion: v1
items:

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ResourceQuota
  metadata:
  name:
  namespace:
  spec:
  hard:
  hdd-ceph-block.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: 10Gi
  hdd-ceph-fs.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage: 10Gi

Can I get a  value , key is  'hdd-ceph-fs.storageclass.storage.k8s.io/requests.storage'
???

Answer (score 1):

I finally tried it out!

```sh
kubectl get secret something -o jsonpath={.data.hello\\.world}
```